# How to set grid size to 1 mm

Tags: units, measurement

I have set the Unit to `millimetres` unit Scale to `0.001` and Grid Scale to `0.01`. But still, one box in the grid measures 1.43 mm as shown in the screenshot. How can I correctly set one grid box to 1 mm? or am I missing something?

[image]

I am using Blender Version 3.5.0 (3.5.0 2023-03-29)

Comment: Maybe your measurement didn't snap to the verts or your verts aren't planar...

Comment: Is that an edge of an object? Is the object scale applied?

Comment: I just set the unit scale and scale of the floor to the values you did and the grid is 1mm here, so the issue is not the actual size of the grid but how the measurement you see in your screenshot is being done.

Comment: @LeoAguiarAll there vertices are on z0, so I think it is planar

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati I added a plane mesh and removed the face, now it has only vertices and edges. I am a noob, not sure how to set the object scale :|

Comment: In object mode, select the object. Check if the 'scale' values in the transform panel are all set to "1.000". My guess is they aren't. If they are set to any other values, press ctrl+a and select "scale". This will 'apply' the scale of the object, making the scale values all 1, but without changing the actual dimensions of the object. 
If my assumption is correct, then  after appying the scale the edge you are measuring will give out the correct measurement of 1 mm.